# Disabling the nav bar when user back swipes on iOS using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i have a class which disables the user from using the backswipe gesture to go back to the previous page on the iOS platform, this code works but the Navigation Side bar still appears when the user does the backswipe gesture, is their a way to disable this feature as well.

My current code stopping backswipe:

```
 using DisableSwipe.iOS;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), 
 typeof(NoBackSwipeRenderer))]
 namespace DisableSwipe.iOS
{
public class NoBackSwipeRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (ViewController != null && ViewController.NavigationController != null)
            ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;



    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the "Navigation Side bar" You mean the menu? Are you using a master-detail view?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes thats it , my mistake. Yeah using a master-detail view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `IsGestureEnabled="false"` in you Xaml code of MasterDetailPage like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sample.Views" 
                  x:Class="Sample.Views.MainPage"
                  IsGestureEnabled="false">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the swipe gesture on a MasterDetail view you can simply use the `IsGestureEnabled` property. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage.isgestureenabled?view=xamarin-forms